# Has anybody a complete list of Obelisks in the World?

Tags: art, archaeology, prehistory

I'm interested to see if we can build up a full list of all Obelisks around the world.
It would be great to have the coordinates of each location, so I can mark them on Google Earth.

Yes, I did do a Google search and it came up with an old question on this forum and on skyscrapercity.

So I would like to see what knowledge we have about these symbols of Ra.
(Edit 20th February) 
By which I mean any Obelisks of significant size.

I want to see if their location and time of construction is linked to center of cultural dominance. 
I find it intriguing that the Washington layout matches the one in the Vatican St Peter square.

I would like to find any older and newer.

Comment: _"about these symbols of Ra"_ wait, wait, are you interested in _all_ obelisks, or only in Ra's?

Comment: The wikipedia page for obelisks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obelisk) has a list of the current locations of know ancient and modern obelisks. Shouldn't be too much effort to geocode the locations to get the co-ordinates.

Comment: Are u interested in somewhat notable obelisks? Any military cemetry or even a place of some WWII common grave would have some obelisks.

Comment: I learn something new everyday here; like the fact that the Washington Monument is a "Symbol of Ra"

Comment: Symbol of Ra is not necessarily be officially announced of course. That is more about the original purpose of these obelisks.

Answer (score 1):

The list from the Wikipedia:

```
Egypt – 8
    Pharaoh Thutmosis I, Karnak Temple, Luxor
    Pharaoh Ramses II, Luxor Temple
    Pharaoh Hatshepsut, Karnak Temple, Luxor
    Pharaoh Senusret I, Al-Masalla area of Al-Matariyyah district in Heliopolis, Cairo
    Pharaoh Ramses III, Luxor Museum
    Pharaoh Ramses II, Gezira Island, Cairo, 20.4 m (67 ft)[16]
    Pharaoh Ramses II, Cairo International Airport, 16.97 m (55.7 ft)
    Pharaoh Seti II, Karnak Temple, Luxor, 7 m (23 ft)
France – 1
    Pharaoh Ramses II, Luxor Obelisk, in Place de la Concorde, Paris
Israel – 1
    Caesarea obelisk
Italy – 11 (includes the only one located in the Vatican City)
    Rome — 8 ancient Egyptian obelisks (see List of obelisks in Rome)
    Piazza del Duomo, Catania (Sicily)
    Benevento, two obelisk.
    Boboli Gardens (Florence)
    Urbino
Poland – 1
    Ramses II, Poznań Archaeological Museum, Poznań (on loan from Ägyptisches Museum und Papyrussammlung, Berlin)[17]
Turkey – 1
    Pharaoh Tuthmosis III, in Square of Horses, Istanbul
United Kingdom – 4
    Pharaoh Tuthmosis III, "Cleopatra's Needle", on Victoria Embankment, London
    Pharaoh Amenhotep II, in the Oriental Museum, University of Durham
    Pharaoh Ptolemy IX, Philae obelisk, at Kingston Lacy, near Wimborne Minster, Dorset
    Pharaoh Nectanebo II, British Museum, London (pair of obelisks)
United States – 1
    Pharaoh Tuthmosis III, "Cleopatra's Needle", in Central Park, New York
```

Comment: As understand the Wikipedia list only includes obelisks of ancient Egypt origin.